# Using gedit, how can I jump to the location of an error? (jump to next error shortcut)

Tags: compiler-errors, shortcut, gedit

I'd like my students to be able to run the compiler from within `gedit` and when there are errors, have a keyboard shortcut to jump directly to the source code containing the next error.  I know how to do this in emacs (M-x compile followed by C-x `).  Does anyone know how to set up something similar in gedit?

Answer (score 1):

check out [Gedit source code builder plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geditbuilderplg/).  Normally, the compiler output are not captured.

Comment: Use the *mouse*?  I'd just as soon wear a ball and chain.  But the plugin looks useful; thanks +1

Comment: just don't have any compiler errors in the first place, then it wouldn't be a problem!  j/k =)